# Chrome extension create html page at the root

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Currently my extension opens a web page at

> chrome-extension://bpmcncockdffdifceihffkimpfbobjhn/dist/webpage.html

How do I make it so that the webpage.html is omitted, and that the following url:

> chrome-extension://bpmcncockdffdifceihffkimpfbobjhn

Immediately points to the webpage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chrome extensions pages are treated as direct file URLs, not as server pages, so there is no default handler for directories like `index.html`.

#### Persistent background script

If your background script **doesn't** have `"persistent": false` in manifest.json you can use [webRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) API to redirect such a fake URL into the real one:

manifest.json:

```js
"permissions": ["webRequest"],
"background": {
  "persistent": true,
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(e => {
  return {redirectUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('/dist/webpage.html')};
}, {
  urls: [chrome.runtime.getURL('/')],
  types: ['main_frame'],
}, ['blocking']);
```

#### Event page background script

If your background script has `"persistent": false` in manifest.json you can use [webNavigation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation) API to redirect an error page to the real page. The only nuisance is that there'll be a dummy item in the tab's history and the history back button will be active (but it won't work of course as it'll be redirected again).

manifest.json:

```js
"permissions": ["webNavigation"],
"background": {
  "persistent": false,
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
}
```

background.js:

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onErrorOccurred.addListener(({tabId}) => {
  chrome.tabs.update(tabId, {url: '/dist/webpage.html'});
}, {
  url: [{
    urlEquals: chrome.runtime.getURL('/'),
  }],
});
```

There is also [declarativeWebRequest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest) but only in Chrome beta/dev/Canary. And just for fun, it's possible to use webRequest API with nonpersistent event pages but it's hacky (you'll have to prevent unloading of the event page by opening a message connection from an iframe inside the background page) and defeats the purpose of event pages so I won't be showing it here.